# getrequeststream in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I want to post a data with HttpWebRequest using MSDN code but getresponse() is not working.

```
System.net.httpwebrequest does not contain a definition for getrequeststream
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

 HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://d.co/login.php");
 myReq.Method = "POST";
 myReq.ContentType = "application/json";
 Stream dataStream = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetRequestStream();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Post your error message so we can have a better idea. And the cases in your `usings` are incorrect

Comment: System.net.httpwebrequest does not contain a definition for getrequeststream, using are OK

Comment: What platform are you targeting? Are you perhaps on windows phone?

Comment: yes http://postimg.org/image/5irxy9bx1/

Comment: Sigh. That is important context. Say so next time, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method does not exist on Windows Phone, because you are many to use async IO constantly. You need `GetRequestStreamAsync` or `BeginGetRequestStream`. The `*Async` method is usually easier to understand and use than `Begin*`, but requires an up-to-date compiler. The relevant example is here, in the phone a based documentation: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Net.HttpWebRequest(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Net.HttpWebRequest%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: @user3529738 I genuinely have no idea how to respond to that statement.

Comment: do you have shorter one

Comment: @user sure: here's how you make it shorter: you use the example to understand what is going on, then when you write it locally you only use the bits you need. Also, as noted: using async/await on the *Async methods will remove the need for multiple methods, making it more readable

Comment: can webclient class support retrieving php cookies?